# Flutter : Scroll parent ListView when children ListView reach bottom inside NestedScroll View body

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K5ELKDKso7Nvmx6VPLilD1yeId7YziCm/view?usp=sharing

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabsList.length,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Nested Scroll View Example1'),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView(
        
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: ScrollController(),
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                // controller: ScrollController(),
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),));}
```